.jar files wont open on double click
Anytime I attempt to open a .jar file by double clicking (despite it being executable), it gives me the following error: Could not find the program 'cautious-launcher' . However, if I run it through terminal by using java -jar it works. Whats the issue? This did not happen in previous versions of Ubuntu, (I am currently using Kubuntu 24.04.1)

What worked for me was running:
sudo nano /usr/share/applications/*java.desktop

And removing the "cautious-launcher"
So it ended up looking like this
Exec=/usr/bin/java -jar %f

And to update these changes run
xdg-mime default openjdk-21.desktop application/x-java-archive

Or what ever java version you are using
